# How to maintain Lucene index availability during rebuild?

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6

When rebuilding indexes on a content delivery server, any components that search that index fail (blow up).  **How can I rebuild my index without causing the search components to be unavailable?**  Furthermore, is there a standard way to handle this?

The code I'm using to perform the reindex on regular intervals:

```
 Sitecore.Data.Database db = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(DBName);
 Index index = db.Indexes[IndexName];
 index.GetSearcher(db).Close();
 index.Rebuild(db);
```

To give a little context:

- Sitecore version - 6.4.1 (rev. 110324)
- It is necessary to rebuild the index because it contains some data from Sitecore and some data from an external system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mark Ursino advices in the post [How to maintain Sitecore Lucene indexes in huge content delivery webfarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887673/how-to-maintain-sitecore-lucene-indexes-in-huge-content-delivery-webfarm):

You can consider using the open source [Sitecore Lucene Refresher](https://github.com/Velir/Sitecore-Lucene-Refresher) that will run a index crawl operation in-memory and will commit the index back to the file system so you don't lose any index content during the rebuild process.

Comment: I had not seen the Sitecore Lucene Refresher.  I will give it a spin.