# Best practice to divide a big task in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

In my ASP.Net MVC4 project I have a method which saves the user entered data. And once the saving is done the same page is reloaded with new values.

However in a new requirement we have a time consuming Index rebuild for search functionality to be added when ever user saves data. Though we were successful in getting it done, the rebuilding is a time consuming task. Hence the user need to wait for considerable amount of time to get the post back action to see the refreshed page.

So I was wondering is there a good practice, to break down this project. As we had previously, the control should return to the user, once the data is saved in DB. While the rebuilding should happen at background.

**Previous Function Prototype.**

```
function saveData()
{
   //Do Saving
   Return Success
}
```

**Current Function**

```
function saveData()
    {
       //Do Saving
       // Rebuild Index
       Return Success
    }
```

Now can I return the success before rebuilding, also I need to do the rebuilding at the back end.

One way we thought was, since we are in Azure we can create a worker role to run this ever few interval. However this is a big overhead since we may not get the user update their profile every now and then. But when ever they do it should run.

Is any inbuilt ASp.net / C# function or architecture  can be used to achieve this? Asynchronusly?

Comment: To be honest, best-practice should dictate that you not have to rebuild indexes every time a record is updated.

Comment: Thanks Moo, Since we are using Lucine Search, the index has to be rebuild to get the new changes affected in the Search functionality.

Comment: You can't do it inside of ASP.NET because you will only get thread aborts unless you wait for the thread to complete. Of course, this would be almost useless. I suggest creating a windows service that listens to an MSMQ queue and drop messages onto the queue from the web application.

Comment: Thanks Keith, Since we are using Azure, I guess it should be a worker role (One more instance then :)) then. What are these Asynchronus programming in C#, will that help me in MVC architecture?

Comment: You could go for a web-service approach. Call it asynchronously. Fire and forget!

Comment: Maybe this can help, in a fire-and-forget scenario http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17949967/how-to-maintain-lucene-index-availability-during-rebuild

Comment: Dear Devraj, we are using Azure , then what should be the architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you need to rebuild lucene indexes all the time,  All you need to do is to remove the old index of the data and just add the new index. With this approach it is going to be fast. Code snippet shown below -

```
private static void _addToLuceneIndex(SampleData sampleData, IndexWriter writer) {
    // remove older index entry
    var searchQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("Id", sampleData.Id.ToString()));
    writer.DeleteDocuments(searchQuery);

    // add new index entry
    var doc = new Document();

    // add lucene fields mapped to db fields
    doc.Add(new Field("Id", sampleData.Id.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
    doc.Add(new Field("Name", sampleData.Name, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    doc.Add(new Field("Description", sampleData.Description, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

    // add entry to index
    writer.AddDocument(doc);
}
```

Ref - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/320219/Lucene-Net-ultra-fast-search-for-MVC-or-WebForms

Comment: Thanks Rami, For the good suggesstion. Though we solved the issue by using Task.Factory.Startnew(). we will be looking to implement your suggestions for our project.