# Sitecore indexes multiple CD servers not consistent

Tags: indexing, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I am experiencing inconsistencies with indexes on my CD servers. I have 4 Cd servers, lets call them:

- CD1
- CD2
- CD3
- CD4

I also have 2 databases servers, lets call them:

- DB1
- DB2

The configuration is as follows:

- Sitecore 7.2
- CD1 and CD2 point to DB1
- CD3 and CD4 point to DB2

I am using the EventQueue to handle updates to all of the CD servers. The table is getting populated and appears to be working, just not consistently. If I delete all of the indexes on all of the CD servers then rebuild all indexes and publish from the CA server I see all of the index folders for the indexes on the CD servers are created. The problem is, the actual indexes are empty on some of the CD servers and it seems to be random.

Any ideas on why the indexes are not being built the same on all CD servers?

Comment: What's the value of the `Indexing.UpdateInterval` setting in your web.config?  Also, I'm presuming you're using SQL replication between DB1 and DB2?

Comment: Indexing.UpdateInterval 5 minutes and yes, I am replicating the core db.

Comment: Ok. In the web.config, have you enabled HistoryEngine for the web DB on all CA and CD servers? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887673/how-to-maintain-sitecore-lucene-indexes-in-huge-content-delivery-webfarm

Comment: Yes, I even set it to 5 minutes for testing purposes.

Comment: Try doing a SELECT COUNT(*) on your master db History and EventQueue tables. Any of those counts come out exceedingly high?  Like above 50.000 or so?

Comment: Yes, the record count is high, sometimes reaching 200k.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Sitecore Scalability Settings, please ensure it is correct on the servers where the index are not being rebuilt, that is the Instance Name should be blank and the PublishingInstance should be filled in.

Moreover, check if the information of all your servers are being inserted in the Properties table of Core Database

Thanks